# How I can make the listbox get the items when I search on textbox in different forms

Tags: c#

In Form FrmMain when I press enter to load the link on web browser I wanna get the info (URL) that I put there "txtURL.text" to get the History on form2 "FrmSettings" that is "lstHistory.txt" and make the same for bookmarkers but for that I will click on "bunifuImageButton3_Click" in Form1 but will get the items (Info) on listBox2 in form2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

// 1. Use Easy Tabs
using EasyTabs;
namespace ChromiumBrowser
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();



        }

        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
      

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
            {
                Cef.Initialize( new CefSettings()); 
            }
            // Create a browser component
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            pnlBody.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


            //add events
            chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += ChromeBrowser_LoadingStateChanged;

            chromeBrowser.TitleChanged += ChromeBrowser_TitleChanged;
        }

        private void ChromeBrowser_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                this.FindForm().Text = e.Title; 
            });
        }

        private void ChromeBrowser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                loader.Visible = e.IsLoading;
                txtURL.Text = chromeBrowser.Address;

                iconSecurity.Image = chromeBrowser.Address.StartsWith("https") ? imageList1.Images[0] : imageList1.Images[1];
            });
        }


        // 2. Important: Declare ParentTabs
        protected TitleBarTabs ParentTabs
        {
            get
            {
                return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs);
            }
        }

        private void bunifuLoader1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        
        private void txtURL_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
            {
                LoadUrl(txtURL.Text.Trim());
                
                
            }
        }

        void LoadUrl(string url)
        {
            if(url.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                chromeBrowser.Load(url);
                
            }
            else
            {
                chromeBrowser.Load($"https://www.google.com/search?q={url}");
            }
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(chromeBrowser.CanGoBack)
            {
                chromeBrowser.Back();
            }
        }

        private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chromeBrowser.CanGoForward)
            {
                chromeBrowser.Forward();
            }
        }

        private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chromeBrowser.Reload();
        }

        private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Kimtoo.Backdrop.Show( new FrmSettings());
        }

        private void bunifuImageButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chromeBrowser.Load("https://www.google.com/");
        }

        private void txtURL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, object v)
        {
        }
        private void bunifuImageButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

```
using CefSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChromiumBrowser
{
    public partial class FrmSettings : Form
    {


        public FrmSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void bunifuButton23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch21.Visible = false;
            lstHistory.Visible = true;
            bunifuButton25.Visible = true;
            bunifuToggleSwitch22.Visible= true;
            bunifuToggleSwitch23.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            listBox2.Visible = false;
            bunifuButton26.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch24.Visible = false;
            bunifuSeparator2.Visible = false;

        }

        private void bunifuToggleSwitch21_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bunifuButton25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstHistory.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                }

        private void bunifuToggleSwitch22_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bunifuToggleSwitch22.Checked)
            {
                this.bunifuToggleSwitch23.Checked = false;
            }
          

         

        }

        private void bunifuToggleSwitch23_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bunifuToggleSwitch23.Checked)
            {
                this.bunifuToggleSwitch22.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private void bunifuButton22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch21.Visible = false;
            lstHistory.Visible = false;
            bunifuButton25.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch22.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch23.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            listBox2.Visible= true;
            bunifuButton26.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch24.Visible = false;
            bunifuSeparator2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void bunifuButton26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }

        private void bunifuRating1_ValueChanged(object sender, Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuRating.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bunifuButton24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch21.Visible = false;
            lstHistory.Visible = false;
            bunifuButton25.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch22.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch23.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            listBox2.Visible = false;
            bunifuButton26.Visible = false;
            bunifuSeparator2.Visible = true;
            bunifuToggleSwitch24.Visible = false;
        }

        private void bunifuButton28_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            bunifuToggleSwitch21.Visible = true;
            bunifuToggleSwitch24.Visible = true;
            lstHistory.Visible = false;
            bunifuButton25.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch22.Visible = false;
            bunifuToggleSwitch23.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            listBox2.Visible = false;
            bunifuButton26.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            bunifuSeparator2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```